# C# - Checking Index values of two sets

Tags: c#, linq

From two sets

```
var set1 =new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var set2 =new int[] { 100, 200, 300 };
```

How to check index value of elements in set1 and set 2 ? if index value of elements of set1
equals to index value of elements of set2 then i want that pair like

```
{1,100} ,{2,200},{3,300}.
```

**Some incomplete code**

```
var pairs=from n1 in set1 
          from n2 in (from num in set2 where ((num1,index)=> );
```

Comment: yes exactly both have the same length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can do:

```
var pairs=
  set1.Select((item, index) => new
  {
      n1= item, n2= set2[index]
  }).ToArray();
```

Or if set2 does not have an indexer, get n2 as follows:

```
n2 = set2.Skip(index).Take(1).Single()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this

```
int[] set1 = {1, 2, 3};
int[] set2 = {100, 200, 300};

var t = from i1 in set1
        from i2 in set2
        where Array.IndexOf(set1, i1) == Array.IndexOf(set2, i2)
        select new int[] { i1, i2 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you just want to join these two arrays. This is how I would do it

```
var pairs=from n1 in set1  
          from n2 in set2
          select new
          {
               n1,
               n2
          }
```

This will return both sets combined. This is assuming both sets are already sorted.